# How to devise therapies using neuromotor task training for a child with writing problems?

Tags: treatment-options, disorders

I would like to devise therapies for a child with writing difficulties.
This child has developmental coordination disorder (DCD), therefor he has problems with his fine motor skills.

I would like to treat this child using neuromotor task training, but I struggle to integrate this therapy into fun games.

I thought about using a sandbox and having the child draw circles using a stick. But I struggle with finding a way I could make it more or less difficult for the child.

Comment: Not an answer, but off the top of my head, I wonder if hand-eye coordination tasks would relate to this issue such as playing video games. I'll look into it.

Comment: You could try with a very easy setup and adjust difficult by tools used, figures drawn, position of the child when drawing, left or right hand used etc.?